# How do I extract a value of a JSON with arbitrary key in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a field with type `jsonb` that contains objects with keys and their values. Examples:

```
{"a": "qwe"}
{"b": "rty"}
{"a": "asd", "b": "123"}
```

I need an expression that returns a value in the JSON independently on its key. If there are several keys, I need any of them (first one, for example). The desirable result for the values above is:

```
"qwe"
"rty"
"asd"  -- or "123"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_each_text()` for that:

```
select j.val
from the_table t
  cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(t.the_json_column) as j(k,val);
```

That will return both values, `asd` **and** `123` from the third row

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8131c8e07ffdad66573408ed9c46c74b)

---

An improvement to have one arbitrary value:

```
select j.val
from the_table t
cross join lateral (
    select * from jsonb_each_text(t.the_json_column) as j(k,val)
    limit 1
) j
```